# Meteor: Display API result data on highcharts

Tags: javascript, meteor, highcharts, google-api, youtube-api

I have a page which gets data (daily view count) from a users YouTube channel using the Google API and then I am trying to display this data on a chart using [Highcharts](https://github.com/MaazAli/Meteor-HighCharts/) (line chart). The user can also use a date picker and be able to change the time period for the data that is shown (Example: Last 30 Days, Last week, Last Month, etc.) and I would like to have the chart automatically update once a new time period is selected.

I'm guessing the best way for this is through [ReactiveVars](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) but I'm not having much luck making it work. My API call seems to be working fine, so now I need to have the result output display on my chart.

Here is an example screenshot of my console.log for what my api result looks like (in the rows, each array is a day, 0 is the date and 1 is the corresponding view count):

[image: Console.log of API result]

I would like to have the date data appear along the bottom xAxis of the chart, and then have the view count along the yAxis. Here is an example of what my chart is looking like with the code below (with random example data):

[image: Chart w/ example data & date selector]

Here is my code for the chart/date picker/api call:

```
Template.apps.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
  apiStartDate = new ReactiveVar(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  apiEndDate = new ReactiveVar(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    this.autorun(function(){
    // View API Call
    GoogleApi.get('youtube/analytics/v1/reports', { params: { 'end-date': apiEndDate.get(), metrics: "views", ids: "channel==MINE", 'start-date': apiStartDate.get(), metrics: "views", dimensions: "day", sort: "-day"}}, function(error, result) {
      console.log(result);
});
  });
});

// Views Chart

Template.apps.helpers({
  viewsChart: function() {
    return {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            marginBottom: 50,
            spacingBottom: 40
        },
        title: {
            text: this.username + "'s views"
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Views'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            align:'center',
            y:40
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Channel Name',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    };
  },
});

// Date Picker

Template.apps.rendered = function(){

    $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
        endDate: moment(),
        showDropdowns: true,
        showWeekNumbers: true,
        timePicker: false,
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        timePicker12Hour: true,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        opens: 'left',
        drops: 'down',
        buttonClasses: ['btn', 'btn-sm'],
        applyClass: 'btn-primary',
        cancelClass: 'btn-default',
        separator: ' to ',
        locale: {
            applyLabel: 'Submit',
            cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
            fromLabel: 'From',
            toLabel: 'To',
            customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
            daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr','Sa'],
            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            firstDay: 1
        }
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        // Start/End date - reactive vars to set 'start-date' & 'end-date' API Call params.
        apiStartDate.set(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        apiEndDate.set(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    });
};
```

I've been trying to create Reactive Vars for this but everything I seem to try isn't working, anyone know how I can set this up? Fairly new to Meteor and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Checkout [this article](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/195-meteor-standalone). I think point #3 should be the case you are looking for, at least as good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

**Do it this way:**

```
Template.apps.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this, startDate, endDate;
  self.apiStartDate = new ReactiveVar(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  self.apiEndDate = new ReactiveVar(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    self.autorun(function(){
    // View API Call
       startDate = self.apiStartDate.get();
       endDate = self.apiEndDate.get();
       GoogleApi.get('youtube/analytics/v1/reports', { params: { 'end-date': endDate, metrics: "views", ids: "channel==MINE", 'start-date': startDate, metrics: "views", dimensions: "day", sort: "-day"}}, function(error, result) {
         console.log(result);
       });
  });
});
```

**Same way in rendered:**

```
var self = this;
var startDate = self.apiStartDate.get();
self.apiStartDate.set(new Date());
```

**Suggestion:**

Start using reactiveDict instead of reactiveVar.